# Windows CE: Wakeup device when USB power on

Tags: usb, windows-ce, suspend

I've got a navigation device (Wayteq x850)  that's running Windows CE 5.0. It serves as USB client to another device. Is there a (simple) way to wake up the USB client from Suspend when the USB connection is established, or when power comes from the USB?

Thanks for any kind of hint. Microsoft's MSDN pages ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms836788.aspx , http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms894047.aspx ) are very good at claiming that a lot of things work and are supported, but do not explain at all what to do to get them to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that Windows CE is a modular OS, unlike a desktop OS.  While CE itself supports many things, it's purely up to the OEM to decide if they will implement or include support for a feature in an actual platform.

In this case, you can get the device to wake on connection (assuming it doesn't now) only if you have access to the driver code and the ability to update the driver/OS of the target.

Essentially you need to handle the interrupt generated when the cable is connected and plumb that through to the power manager to tell the system to wake.  It's likely to be very little code, but unless you're the device OEM, it's highly unlikely you'll be able to implement it.

Comment: thanks. That helped. It's not always the best news that something will not work, but at least you know you can stop prowling MSDN.